# Detect Enclosed ArUco Marker Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, aruco, pose-estimation

I am trying to use the Enclosed ArUco Marker in Python but it cannot be detected. Is there an implementation of this ArUco Marker detection in python and how do i use it ?

The reason why I want to use markers with with the enclosed corners is because the sub-pixel corner refinement should be more accurate.

Below are 2 images of the markers. One with the Enclosed Corners and the same without the enclosed corners:

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I try to parse your marker with `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers` it can detect all the markers from the tutorial but yours is rejected. Are you sure this is an aruco marker? Where did you get it from? Any specification?

Comment: Hi, i found this marker from this paper (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QU9KoBtjSM2kF6ITOjQ76xqL7H0TEtXriJX5kwi9Kgc/edit#) and there is also a youtube video about it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4uioaSB8BM).  This marker seems to have a more accurate corner detection because of its enclosed corners.

Comment: "aruco" (AR markers in general) is a bunch of techniques. in practice, nobody's localizing "corners", but edges, because a whole edge gives a lot more subpixel information than a single saddlepoint/corner. next is pose recovery from those four points. the *decoding* of the "modules" (pixels) in the marker is again separate. -- OpenCV's aruco is one monolithic module and I'm unaware of any modes that would tolerate _this_ type of boundary.

Comment: Even if I remove the enclosing, the remaining marker is not recoginzed by `cv2.aruco`. Hence, it is not contained in the standard dictionaries for 6x6 markers. You can try the library mentioned in the paper, which is in c++ and built open opencv. For python there is a wrapper project but it's not very well supported. I would recommend to use "normal" aruco markers like used in the `cv2.aruco`-tutorials. If you have issues with those please rephrase your question.

Comment: Thanks alot for the Information. I have updated the Images ( with and without the enclosed corners). The reason why I want to test this is because of the subpixel corner refinement. I will have a look at this wrapper Project. Do you know if there are more accurate implimentaions of aruco markers for Pose Estimation?